# react-native-navigation startTabBasedApp not working on Auth0Lock completion from startSingleScreenApp

Tags: react-native, auth0

"react-native-navigation": "^2.0.0-experimental.133"

In order to use Auth0lock for login and profile creation a single screen app is started which on login, should call startTabBasedApp and transition to tabbed app. What I am seeing is that auth0 view is popped and I am left in my single screen app root. Log suggests that the app is started. Reloading works as expected, but at that point I never go to Auth0lock view. Any suggestions?